# T-SQL: Get top n records by column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Struggling with what's probably a very simple problem. I have a query like this:

```
 ;WITH rankedData
       AS ( -- a big, complex subquery)
  SELECT UserId,
         AttributeId,
         ItemId
  FROM   rankedData
  WHERE  rank = 1
  ORDER  BY datEventDate DESC
```

The sub-query is designed to grab a big chunk of interlined data and rank it by itemId and date, so that the rank=1 in the above query ensures we only get unique ItemIds, ordered by date. The partition is:

```
Rank() OVER (partition BY ItemId ORDER BY datEventDate DESC) AS rk
```

The problem is that what I want is the top 75 records for each UserID, ordered by date. Seeing as I've already got a rank inside my sub-query to sort out item duplicates by date, I can't see a straightforward way of doing this.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your query should look like

```
SELECT t.UserId, t.AttributeId, t.ItemId
FROM (
SELECT UserId, AttributeId, ItemId, rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY datEventDate 
        ) 
FROM rankedData
) t
WHERE t.rowid <= 75
```

Comment: If I understand OP correctly he needs `top 75 unique Itemids per user`.

Comment: @Kaf since this query uses the CTE `rankedData` I believe that is what will happen. Or rather, from the unique list this will pick the rows. But come to think of it, you may have a point. Only OP will know.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: I see what you mean. Thanks. There is a one little misunderstanding of user in OP worth mentioning. User thinks **"rank=1 in the above query ensures we only get unique ItemIds"** which is not the case. I think he needs `row_number() instead rank()` within the `cte`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance - you understand correctly and your comments are very helpful. I didn't realise you could levy two partitions against the same table, but it's obvious now you mention it :)